# Удаление отрицательных элементов из списка

Tags: c++, list, список, stl

Нужно удалить все отрицательые элементы списка. Код написал, но в чем-то ошибка, и я никак не могу понять в чем, помогите.

```
for (auto i = myList.begin(); i != myList.end(); i++)
            {
                if (*i < 0)
                {
                    myList.erase(i);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Прочитайте документацию для `erase`, особенно в части инвалидации итераторов.

Comment: `myList.remove_if([](const int& val) {return val < 0;});`?

Comment: @EOF Спасибо, получилось, но не могли бы вы сказать, для чего здесь нужны 
 пустые скобки [ ]?

Comment: [Здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/66021/) можете почитать.